# Is it possible to compile the node.js project with the gcc -E option?

Tags: node.js, gcc

I work on special features on C/C++ code. I need to process in severals steps. The first one is to generate the pre processing of the C includes/macros/etc using the gcc -E command. Is it possible to change the "configure.py" file on the node.js project to be able to accept this option ?
Thanks for your help

Comment: Does node.js use a Makefile? If so, it may be possible to run `make foo.i` to generate the preprocessed version of `foo.c`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is a huge project with multiple files. I have discovered the -save-temps option for gcc. Is it suitable ?

Comment: Here is the answer, thanks to Ben https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/2172